# SQLite specifying columns query

Tags: android, sqlite

Why this works

```
database.rawQuery("select * from Assignments left join Tasks on Tasks._id = Assignments.TaskID left join Flights on Flights.ARR_FLT_ID = Tasks.ArrivalFlightID where Assignments.TaskAccepted='Y' and Tasks.RecordChangedByUI = 'N' and Assignments.AssignedTo=? order by Assignments.AssignedOn desc", new String[]{ String.valueOf(empID) });
```

And this DOES NOT ..

```
database.rawQuery("select Tasks.Aircraft AS Aircraft, Tasks.Discrepancy AS Discrepancy, Flights.ARR_FLT AS ARR_FLT from Assignments left join Tasks on Tasks._id = Assignments.TaskID left join Flights on Flights.ARR_FLT_ID = Tasks.ArrivalFlightID where Assignments.TaskAccepted='Y'  and Tasks.RecordChangedByUI = 'N' and Assignments.AssignedTo=? order by Assignments.AssignedOn desc", new String[]{ String.valueOf(empID) });
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7519758/sqlite-select-query-with-column-names  see my comment lol

Comment: @Selvin .... now I got it what u said back then :) Here I am joining 3 tables each table has it's own _id. So which _id should I get ?

Comment: @user533844 as i wrote there ... "master" so in your case it should be Task._id AS _id i think ... you will get this in onselect or onclick event in spinner/listview as id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Difficult to tell without you explaining further. A possibility is that when you `SELECT *`, the column `_id` is being returned (provided the column exists) which is needed for cursors in Android. In your other `SELECT` statement it is not being selected.

You need to explain further - what you are trying to do, post the logcat/errors produced etc.

Comment: I guess u r right. 10-20 13:54:55.069: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5221): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-20 13:54:55.069: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(5221): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.aa.me.vianet/com.aa.me.vianet.activity.MyTask}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist

Comment: It says, _id doesn't exist. So what can I do for that ?

Comment: Here I am joining 3 tables each table has it's own _id. So which _id should I get ?

Comment: Depends if you need an ID, if not, just select any ID from any table, just the once. You can just do `0 as _id`, that would still work.

Comment: Or better yet, rowid. Still, looks like you've solved it. :) Mark me as the answered question. :D